# Use $scope variable as array index

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an array or 'players', and each player has a name, a score and other properties.

I have the following in my partial:

```
<select ng-model="personToAsk">
    <option value=''>Select who you want to ask</option>
    <option ng-repeat="p in players" value="{{$index}}">{{p.name}} ({{p.score}} points)</option>
</select>
<p>Selected player: {{selectedPerson.name}}
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.selectedPerson = $scope.players[$scope.personToAsk];
```

But `{{selectedPerson.name}}` is not outputting anything.

If I hardcode the index in my players array (`$scope.selectedPerson = $scope.players[0];`), it does output the person, but how do I get to be dynamic, so when a player is selected in the dropdown, it shows the name only further down.

If I put `{{personToAsk}}` in my template, it does output a number.

Comment: 1) It rather should be $scope.selectedPerson = $scope.personToAsk. 2) Are you sure that you do this assignment in the right place (in response to the event) ?

Comment: 1)$scope.personToAsk is the $index of the selected option, so I was trying to use that number to retrieve it form the players array. 2) I was hoping that the dynamic binding would take care of things, but I'm new to AngularJS, so I obviously misunderstood how that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all seems kind of messed up. I dont know what variable 'index' is for example etc.

You should use ngOptions to generate the options of the select.

Suppose you have this in your controller:

```
$scope.personToAsk = {};    
$scope.players = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John', score: 10},
    { id: 2, name: 'George', score: 15},
    { id: 3, name: 'James', score: 4}
];
```

Then in your view, just write this:

```
<select ng-model="personToAsk" 
    ng-options="p as (p.name + ' ' + p.score) for p in players">
</select>
<p>Selected player: {{personToAsk.name}}</p>
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/JoeSham/HB7LU/9008/

Comment: The problem is that I want each option to show the name, and score: "John (score: 10)". In your solution, the options only show the name. Is there a way with ng-option to specify the format?

Comment: In my solution, it also shows the score. This is the part that specifies what is shown in the options: (p.name + '  ' + p.score). You can modify it as you need, so for the format you need, just change it to: (p.name + ' (score: ' + p.score + ')')

Answer (score 3):

The statement:

```
$scope.selectedPerson = $scope.players[$scope.personToAsk];
```

Executes once at the time of initialization. And at that time there is no value in $scope.personToAsk.

So, this statement needs to be executes when ever the value in select dropdown changes.
So you can either create a watch on "personToAsk" or have a ng-change on select. And execute this statement there. Should work :)

Watch example:

```
$scope.$watch('personToAsk'), function() {
    $scope.selectedPerson = $scope.players[$scope.personToAsk] ;
}
```

ng-change example:

`<select ng-model="personToAsk" ng-change="selectPerson()">
    <option value=''>Select who you want to ask</option>
    <option ng-repeat="p in players" value="{{$index}}">
        {{p.name}} ({{p.score}} points)
    </option>
</select>`

In Controller:

```
$scope.selectPerson = fucntion() {
    $scope.selectedPerson = $scope.players[$scope.personToAsk];
}
```

Both should work :)

I would personally prefer using ng-options directive to render the options.

Comment: I also wanted to use ng-option, just that I couldn't figure out how to get the output in the options as I wanted: "John (score: 10)".